# Access address book in the background

Tags: xcode, addressbook

I've been trying to set up a way to get a name all the people in a user's address book along with their (multiple) phone numbers, but my attempts aren't working and when I log the array that is supposed to contain the names of the contacts, it returns as NULL.

Here is the code I'm using. Also, I have imported the correct supporting files for the Address Book. I do have a feeling that the array is returning null because of the way the addressBook is being created, but I am not sure if that is the case or how to fix it. Any help would be really useful!

```
//main code 
- (void)getPersonOutOfAddressBook
{

CFErrorRef error = NULL;
ABAddressBookRef addressBook = ABAddressBookCreateWithOptions(NULL, &error);

if (addressBook != nil) {
    NSLog(@"Succesful.");


    NSArray *allContacts = (__bridge_transfer NSArray *)ABAddressBookCopyArrayOfAllPeople(addressBook);

        //testing. This returns NULL
        NSLog(@"%@", allContacts);

    NSUInteger i = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < [allContacts count]; i++)
    {
        ABRecordRef contactPerson = (__bridge ABRecordRef)allContacts[i];
        NSString *firstName = (__bridge_transfer NSString *)ABRecordCopyValue(contactPerson,kABPersonFirstNameProperty);
        NSString *lastName = (__bridge_transfer NSString *)ABRecordCopyValue(contactPerson, kABPersonLastNameProperty);
        NSString *fullName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@", firstName, lastName];

    }

    CFRelease(addressBook);
} else {

    NSLog(@"Error reading Address Book");
}
}

//checking if access is allowed

- (void)checkForAddressBookAccess
{
    ABAddressBookRef addressBookRef = ABAddressBookCreateWithOptions(nil, nil);

if (ABAddressBookRequestAccessWithCompletion == NULL)
{
    // iOS5 
    [self getPersonOutOfAddressBook];
    return;
}
else
{
    // iOS6
    if (ABAddressBookGetAuthorizationStatus() == kABAuthorizationStatusNotDetermined)
    {
        ABAddressBookRequestAccessWithCompletion(addressBookRef, ^(bool granted, CFErrorRef error) {
            if(error)
            {
                //error
            }
            else
            {
                [self getPersonOutOfAddressBook];
            }
        });
    }
    else if (ABAddressBookGetAuthorizationStatus() == kABAuthorizationStatusAuthorized)
    {
        [self getPersonOutOfAddressBook];
    }
    else
    {
       //error
    }
}
}
```